# jQuery Validate - regex for letters with accented letters (Czech)

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, jquery-validate

I created a custom jQuery Validate rule:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function(value, element, regexp) {
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
        },
        "Please check your input."
    );
```

And now would need regex to match only letters (in any language, especial Czech)

I tried

```
regex: "/^\pL++$/uD"

regex: "^\w*(\s\w*)?$"
```

None of these work. What would be the correct regex?

Answer (score 2):

That's because JS doesn't natively support unicode categories. You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode) for more info on this.

Alternatively you could specify a unicode character class with different ranges if you didn't need to know whether or not a unicode character was a "letter" or not. For example:

```
^[\u0000-\u024F]+$
```

would ensure the string contains only control characters and all forms of latin characters including all extensions. You can refer [here](http://unicode-table.com/en) for more characters and ranges.

Comment: The example you provided seems to return true also for numbers...?

Comment: It's just an example. Tailor the character class range to fit your needs by referencing the table.